# Xamarin бесплатен?

Tags: android, c#, ios, xamarin

Можно ли использовать Xamarin бесплатно делая на нём коммерческие программы?

Comment: Тут должна быть шутка про фатальный недостаток, но ее не будет. В общем-то на Xamarin накладываются ограничения Visual Studio. То есть если вы используете VS ниже `Professional` или `Interprise`, то лицензия ограничена для крупных предприятий ([см. тут ограничения](https://store.xamarin.com/) и [тут ограничения](https://www.xamarin.com/compare-visual-studio) и [лиц. соглашение VS Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/license-terms/mt171547/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fstore.xamarin.com%2F)).

Comment: т.е. для коммерческого использования Community нельзя использовать? А ведь есть же ещё Xamarin Studio.

Comment: т.е. xamarin нельзя использовать на бесплатной лицензии если вы являетесь частью крупной компании или количество человек в вашей команде больше четырех. Исключением являются open source, а так же обучающая и научная деятельность.

Comment: В остальном ограничений нет, коммерческое использование не запрещается и вся функциональность доступна в полном объеме.

Comment: Т.е. как индивидуальный разработчик я могу использовать Xamarin в коммерческих целях? Я просто реально запутался и поэтому решил спросить тут.

Comment: Да, как индивидуальный разработчик можете использовать в коммерческих целях.

Comment: Если вы работаете в крупной компании, и используете Xamarin в комерчиских целях и зарабатываете деньги то вы должны платить за использование (как налоги на прибыль), но если вы мелкий не зарегистрированый стартап, хоть винду крякнутую используйте, никто и слова не скажет)

Comment: оффтопик - не имеет отношения к программированию

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko вроде бы решили, что вопросы по использованию ПО для разработки (в том числе по лицензированию) тематичны: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/717/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-windows

Comment: @defaultlocale не нашел в вашей ссылке про лицензирование. В любом случае, я считаю, что вопрос надо закрыть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Итак Xamarin нельзя использовать на бесплатной лицензии если вы являетесь частью крупной компании или количество человек в вашей команде больше четырех. Исключением являются open source, а так же обучающая и научная деятельность.

Если же вы являетесь индивидуальным разработчиком то можете использовать Xamarin в коммерческих целях.

Спасибо уважаемому @Alex Krass